# How to add values in Python Array on Run-time?

Tags: python, arrays, list, input, arduino

I have a program that reads the digital pins of Arduino Board. The Board returns output if Digital Pin is PULLUP(Keyword) means Digital Pin is ON as "b'1'" and "b'0'" if PULLDOWN(Keyword) means Digital Pin is OFF. If output is b'0' i am adding 0 in the array and 1 if output is b'1' and Finally print them. But it gives error. Code is below:

```
from serial import Serial
import time

arduinodata = Serial("COM4",9600)
a=1
i=0
current=0
data=[]
while (a<9):
    binary = arduinodata.read()
    if(binary==b'1'):
        data[i].append(1)
        i=i+1
        a=a+1
    if(binary==b'0'):
        data[i].append(0)
        current=i
        i=i+1
        a=a+1

for b in data:
    print(data[b])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
    File "GettingBitStatus.py", line 12, in <module>       
 data[i].append(1)    
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GettingBitStatus.py", line 12, in <module>
    data[i].append(1)
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue is in these lines:

```
data[i].append(1)
data[i].append(0)
```

Below is the right way to write these lines:

```
data.append(1)
data.append(0)
```

Final Code without error:

```
from serial import Serial
import time

arduinodata = Serial("COM4",9600)
a=1
i=0
current=0
data=[]
while (a<9):
    binary = arduinodata.read()
    if(binary==b'1'):
        data.append(1)
        a=a+1
    if(binary==b'0'):
        data.append(0)
        current=i
        a=a+1

for b in data:
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the append method on an item in the list, not the list itself.

Try the following:

```py
from serial import Serial
import time

arduinodata = Serial("COM4",9600)
a=1
i=0
current=0
data=[]
while (a<16):
    binary = arduinodata.read()
    if(binary==b'1'):
        data.append(1)
        i=i+1
    if(binary==b'0'):
        data.append(0)
        current=i
        i=i+1

for b in data:
    print(b)
```

a more pythonic approach using list comprehension would be something like

```py
from serial import Serial
arduinodata = Serial("COM4",9600)
data = [ int(arduinodata.read()) for _ in range(16) ]
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe it gives the exact the error. Because this solution removes the calling of an element in the array..